# Word to PDF Conversion - large object file

Tags: macos, pdf, microsoft-word-2011

Using 2011 Word for Mac, I created a word document with embedded a few JPG of 40kB each.  The saved Word (.docx) file is only 300kB, but if I save as PDF, the resultant file is 4MB - too large to post on my website.  How do I get a smaller PDF file (Preview quartz filter saving to small file makes no difference)?

Comment: Firstly, do the images have to stay high resolution? Secondly, does it explicitly have to be in PDF format?

Comment: Adobe Acrobat can reduce the size of the generated .pdf.  Of course a couple 40kb images wouldn't create a 4MB file.

Comment: Have you tried optimization while exporting to pdf. It has options which reduce size.

Comment: Thanks all for your thoughts, but have done all you suggest.  The word source File was optimised using the Reduce File Size option, and all embedded jpgs (6, each less than 40k) were optimised to 96 dpi size.  There were no HiRes photos, and the Mac PDF Editor - Preview - yet Word exported the file in pdf from 350k to 4.2MB.  Using Mac's Preview functions of reducing file size (quartz) filter actually took the pdf object file from 4.2MB to 4.3MB.  Adobe Acrobat was employed to open and close the pdf file using reduce file options, but the file stayed at 4.3MB.